# When import js file, the inherit method does not available

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a js file like this

```
export function A() {
    this.aTest() = function(){
        // This work fine
    }
}

function B() {
    this.bTest = function() {
        // this function will not available when import
    }
}

A.prototype = new B();
A.constructor = A;
```

And in angular project, I import this file

...

```
let test = new A();
test.aTest(); => work fine
test.bTest() ; => TS2339: Property bTest does not exist on type A
```

- bTest is working fine with js project
- How can I import the js with all inherit method ?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? This looks like a TS error.

Comment: Yes. Because I just type direct maybe syntax not correct, the problem is A.prototype = new B().  When import to typescript. A will not inherit B. I just work around by using A.prototype.test = new B(); => now A.test will inherit from B

Answer (score 0):

This is a type check error. `function A()` is an old-version JS style class, not a real class. TS compiler can not recognize `A` as a class. you can add type defines for `A` and `B`.

For example, you JS file name is `a-test.js`, then you can write a `a-test.d.ts` file as below:

```js
export declare class A extends B {
  constructor();
  aTest(): void;
}

export declare class B {
  constructor();
  bTest(): void;
}
```

Comment: Actually this is a 3rd lib that why I must figure out how to use it without (or minimum) update it

Comment: @Wolf You don't need to change it. Just learn about how to add type definitions for 3rd-party lib. You can read this [article](https://medium.com/@ofir3322/add-your-own-type-definition-to-any-javascript-3rd-party-module-1fc6b11e6f10)